# Can a program be stored in flash memory on raspberry pi and run without a monitor and internet connection like on an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, remote, internet

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm new to Pi and Arduino, and couldn't really find an answer through Googling. I'm designing a project that needs some sort of "brain" which will use PID to control relays turning on and off, and I'm unsure whether I should use Pi or Arduino. I would like to be able to write the code for the project then store it on the board I will be using and have it operate continuously without an internet connection or other computer / monitor (just a power supply). I believe Arduino can do this according to this post I found on another site: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/save-program-to-board/38100

My question is, can any version of a Raspberry Pi do the same thing, or does it require an internet connection to run any code I write?

Comment: why woukd it require an internet connection?

Comment: An ethernet or wifi connection would be handy so you can fix things from another computer on the network if they go wrong. .

Comment: Both a USB thumb drive and SD cards use a form of Flash storage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pi just needs a boot medium and some storage.  This is commonly an inserted SD card but for recent model Pis this could be a USB stick instead.

An attached screen and keyboard (and internet) is a convenience when originally programming the Pi.  They are not needed once programming is completed.

Use an Arduino (or Raspberry Pi Pico) if you want a battery power solution and low processing capability.

Use a Raspberry Pi (not a Pico) if you can run off mains or you need lots of processing power.

Answer (score 2):

All rpi's can do what you ask. They boot from sd card or other usb medium and can operate without internet connection. However on the cost side, I would say that it will cost you more to use a Pi for such a project. Except if you do it with pico.